# Direct cable to board compact assembly?

Tags: connector, cables, cable-assemblies, interconnect

I am looking to attach a cable to board in the most compact (yet manufacturable) way possible.  This does not need to be disassembled ever, it can be a permanent connection.

Is there a standard way of attaching cable-to-board without a connector?  Can it be done in a way that can be mass-produced, and does not occupy much room?  Something like a reflow-solderable ribbon cable :)

I need 48-50 wires (possibly 3x 16 or 3x 18).  These are low-frequency analog signals (<1kHz), they can be shielded similar to audio cable, or just rely on the enclosure shield; no special high-speed stuff is needed.  In this case each signal pair goes to a different location 5-10 inches away, so they would split once away from the board (FFC cable or ribbon won't work, split-ribbon may be ok).  Space is at a premium: a standard 0.1 inch header is much too bulky.  Ideally I'd like an assembled height of <2mm and board area <30x10mm. I've looked at Hirose DF-9 or DF-19 and JAE FI-X or FI-R connectors and cables as used for LCD displays - while fairly compact even these are bulkier than I'd like (and the typical cables made for these don't even use all pins, and add significant cost).  Surely there must be a better way?

Comment: Why not look at 0.05" headers? Samtec.com has many options for both headers and board to cable and a nice online catalog.

Comment: @Passerby:  Interesting, I had a look.  These seem to be ~5mm tall (just the connector, not mated).  That seems a bit large?

Comment: They have standard and non-standard heights available. But look at the entire catalog, they have different types of connectors too.

Answer (score 1):

Why not go with direct wire-to-board IDC connectors? They do not satisfy your ideal case, but they are still quite small:
Digikey 3240-50-00-ND is 50 pins (2x25), it is 3.x36mm on board with 5mm height